completing the space $\mathscr{X}$ respect to the norm defined by each of the inner products
Describe the Hilbert spaces obtained by completing the space $\mathscr{X}$ in Example 1.2 with respect to the norm defined by each of the inner products given there.
This example is given as follows
1.2. Example. Let $\mathscr{X}$ be the collection of all sequences $\left\{\alpha_n: n \geqslant 1\right\}$ of scalars $\alpha_n$ from $\mathbb{F}$ such that $\alpha_n=0$ for all but a finite number of values of $n$. If addition and scalar multiplication are defined on $\mathscr{X}$ by
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left\{\alpha_n\right\}+\left\{\beta_n\right\} & \equiv\left\{\alpha_n+\beta_n\right\}, \\
\alpha\left\{\alpha_n\right\} & =\left\{\alpha \alpha_n\right\},
\end{aligned}
$$
then $\mathscr{X}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$.
If $u\left(\left\{\alpha_n\right\},\left\{\beta_n\right\}\right) \equiv \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \alpha_{2 n} \bar{\beta}_{2 n}$, then $u$ is a semi-inner product that is not an inner product. On the other hand,
\begin{aligned}
& \left\langle\left\{\alpha_n\right\},\left\{\beta_n\right\}\right\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \alpha_n \bar{\beta}_n, \\
& \left\langle\left\{\alpha_n\right\},\left\{\beta_n\right\}\right\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \alpha_n \bar{\beta}_n, \\
& \left\langle\left\{\alpha_n\right\},\left\{\beta_n\right\}\right\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^5 \alpha_n \bar{\beta}_n,
\end{aligned}
I'm having trouble knowing how to approach this. For the first inner product my thought was the corresponding norm is
$$||\{\alpha_n\}||^2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\alpha_n|^2$$
Therefore, if $\{\alpha_n\}_m$ is cauchy then by completion of the reals we have $||\{\alpha_n\}_m||^2$ converges to a positive real number. It follows that our completion should be all $\ell_2$ sequences? Note that this means we are adding sequences where it's possible for a infinite number of elements to be nonzero.
Would the other two be
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}|\alpha_n|^2 < \infty, \quad \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^5|\alpha_n^m|^2 < \infty$$
Is there a more explicit characterization of this or is this the best we can do?

Just because the sequences obtained by taking the limit are in a certain space does not mean that the whole space can be reached that way. For example, this won't work with the $\infty$ norm (I know it's not a Hilbert space norm but it's another classical example).

It can be helpful for others to mention this is Exercise 4 in Chapter I, Section 1 of "A Course in Functional Analysis" by Conway.
